# Addressing Different Screen Resolutions In Xamarin.Forms? Scaling Elements?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin mobile development and I've been working on my first Xamarin.Forms cross platform application.

At it's current state, the UI looks perfect on my Huawei Nexus, however, sadly there's a problem.

During the development and testing, debugging process so far I've been **only** using iPhone 6 Plus and Nexus 7 emulators and Nexus 6P as a physical device **assuming** (to my mistake) that Xamarin will take care of scaling everything to devices with smaller screens, however, that turned out to be completely false.

The moment I attempted to run the application on an emulator with smaller screen, say iPhone 4/5, the UI completely broke down and looked out of place (reference image: http://i.imgur.com/bSMQcuW.png ), and now I'm left wondering, exactly what I did wrong.

The idea of UI in given picture is the following: Grid which contains of Rows containing nested Grid which contains Label and ButtonGroup (XLabs).

```
var Grid = new Grid
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    ColumnDefinitions =
    {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
    }
};

var TextLabel = new Label 
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, 
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, 
    FontSize = 18, TextColor = Color.Black 
};

var VarButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup
{
    IsNumber = true,
    Rounded = true,
    ViewBackgroundColor = Color.White,
    BorderColor = Color.White,
    OutlineColor = Color.White,
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0099cc"),
    TextColor = Color.White,
    SelectedTextColor = Color.White,
    SelectedBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
    SelectedBorderColor = Color.White,
    SelectedFrameBackgroundColor = Color.White,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Padding = new Thickness(10),
    Items = RadioButtonValues,
    Scale = 1,
    SelectedIndex = -1
 };
```

I know that you can customize the code to be platform specific using Device.OnPlatform() however that does not seem to appear to fix anything.

Xamarin.Forms given documentation only shows the differences between platforms as far as the scaling goes (iOS/Android/WinPhone), however it does not explain how one goes on about addressing phones with multiple of different screen sizes/resolutions - or perhaps I've missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizes are display independent. That means, that Xamarin.Forms uses the platform specific mechanisms to calculate the absolute pixel dimensions.

**Example**

A view that is 1*1 px on a 320*480 px display (wich is e.g. the base unit on iOS) will be 2*2 px on a 640*960 px and a 640*1136px display.

This means for you: Usually you don't have to care about the resolution.

What you can do is to provide different layouts based on the `Device.Idiom`. Here is an example for that: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/bringing-xamarin-forms-apps-to-tablets/

Comment: I found OnIdiom to be a bit tedious and verbose so I wrote some simple attached properties on a recent project to make it easier to specify different values for tablet and phone. Basically I defaulted to the phone value and optionally specified a value via attached property to use if it was a tablet, worked pretty well.

Comment: Yes it's tedious. It always depends on your needs. If you just want to distinct roughly between tablet and phone, it's ok. But if you have well defined requirements (like we had "tablet view should be shown if display size >= 6 inches") then you have to do something custom.